# Function argument to call only part of a column name (ggplot)

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have succeded in building my first function i R. 
I would now like to improve it, but don´t know how.

My dataset contains many variabels that have "mirror"variabels with almost the same name. The only naming difference is that the "mirror" variable has a "c" in front of the name.

The function plots comparisons of a variabel (VAR) and it´s "mirror" (cVAR).

Simplified dataset and simplified function code that reproduces the challenge:

```
library(ggplot2)  
df <- data.frame(
    X = 1:10+rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5),
    cX = 1:10+rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5),
    Y = 1:10+rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5),
    cY = 1:10-rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5))


compare <- function(VAR, cVAR) {
  VAR <- deparse(substitute(VAR))
  cVAR <- deparse(substitute(cVAR))

  ggplot(df, aes_string(x=VAR, y=cVAR))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm")+
    geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
}

compare(Y, cY)
```

I would like the function to do exactly the same as it does above, but I would like to just have to write compare(Y) instead.

In STATA I would try something like this:

```
y=c`VAR'
```

but I can´t find a similar approach in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
compare <- function(VAR, cVAR) {
  VAR <- deparse(substitute(VAR))
  cVAR <- if(missing(cVAR)) {
    paste0("c", VAR)
  } else {
    deparse(substitute(cVAR))
  }

  stopifnot(all(c(VAR, cVAR) %in% names(df)))

  ggplot(df, aes_string(x=VAR, y=cVAR))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm")+
    geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
}
```

Basically we just use `paste0()` to add in the "c" to the first parameter when the second parameter is not specified.

Then you can run any of these

```
compare(Y) # to cY
compare(X) # to cX
compare(Y, cY)
compare(Y, cX)
```

Comment: Thank you. I see you also improved the function a step further with the stopifnot function. That´s actually very useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you wanted. I simply `paste0` `VAR` with defined `myLetter` and pass `VAR` to `compare()` as character.

```
compare <- function(VAR, myLetter = "c") {
    library(ggplot2)
    VAR2 <- paste0(myLetter, VAR)

    ggplot(df, aes_string(VAR, VAR2))+
        geom_point() +
        geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
        geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
}
compare("Y")
```

[image]